# tf.Dataset will not repeat without - WARNING:tensorflow:Your input ran out of data; interrupting training

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, dataset, tensorflow-datasets

Using Tensorflow's Dataset generator *without* repeat works. However when I use repeat to double my train dataset from 82,000 to 164,000 for additional augmentation I "run out of data."

I've read that steps_per_epoch can "slow cook" models by allowing multiple epochs for a single pass through training data. It's not my intent,  but even when I pass a small number of steps_per_epoch (which should create this slow cooking pattern), TF says I've ran out of data.

There is a case where TF says I'm close ("in this case, 120 batches"). I've attempted plus/minus this value but still getting errors with drop_remainder set to True to drop anything left over.

Error:

> WARNING:tensorflow:Your input ran out of data; interrupting training.
> Make sure that your dataset or generator can generate at least
> `steps_per_epoch * epochs` batches (in this case, 82,000 batches). You
> may need to use the repeat() function when building your dataset.
> WARNING:tensorflow:Your input ran out of data; interrupting training.
> Make sure that your dataset or generator can generate at least
> `steps_per_epoch * epochs` batches (in this case, 120 batches). You
> may need to use the repeat() function when building your dataset.

| Parameters |  |
| --- | --- |
| Train Dataset | 82,000 |
| Val Dataset | 12,000 |
| Test Dataset | 12,000 |
| epochs (early stopping usually stops about 30) | 100 |
| batch_size | 200 |

**batch_size is the same for model mini-batch and generator batches

| Attempt | steps_per_epoch Value | Error |
| --- | --- | --- |
| steps_per_epoch==None | None | "..in this case, 82,000 batches" |
| steps_per_epoch==train_len//batch_size | 820 | "..in this case, 82,000 batches" |
| steps_per_epoch==(train_len//batch_size)-1 | 819 | Training stops halfway "..in this case, 81,900 batches" |
| steps_per_epoch==(train_len//batch_size)+1 | 821 | Training stops halfway "..in this case, 82,100 batches" |
| steps_per_epoch==(train_len//batch_size)//2 | 410 | Training seems complete but errors before validation "..in this case, 120 batches" |
| steps_per_epoch==((train_len//batch_size)//2)-1 | 409 | Same as above:Training seems complete but errors before validation "..in this case, 120 batches" |
| steps_per_epoch==((train_len//batch_size)//2)+1 | 411 | Training seems complete but errors before validation "..in this case, 41,100 batches" |
| steps_per_epoch==(train_len//batch_size)*2 | 1640 | Training stops at one quarter "..in this case, 164,000 batches" |
| steps_per_epoch==20 (arbitrarily small number) | 20 | Very surprisingly "..in this case, 120 batches" |

Generators - goal is to repeat the train set two times:

```
    trainDS = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(trainPaths).repeat(2) 
    train_len = len(trainDS) #used to calc steps_per_epoch
    trainDS = (trainDS
                .shuffle(train_len)
                .map(load_images, num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE)
                .map(augment, num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE)
                .cache('train_cache')
                .batch(batch_size, drop_remainder=True )
                .prefetch(AUTOTUNE)
    )
    valDS = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(valPaths)
    valDS = (valDS
                .map(load_images, num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE)
                .cache('val_cache')
                .batch(batch_size, drop_remainder=True)
                .prefetch(AUTOTUNE)
    )
    testDS = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(testPaths)
    testDS = (testDS
                .map(load_images, num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE)
                .cache('test_cache')
                .batch(batch_size, drop_remainder=True)
                .prefetch(AUTOTUNE)

    )
```

Model.fit()
According to the documentation - len(train)//batch_size is the default

```
    hist= model.fit(trainDS,
                    epochs=epochs, 
                    batch_size=batch_size, 
                    validation_data=valDS,                   
                    steps_per_epoch= <see attempts table above>,
    )
```

EDIT: putting the repeat at the VERY END of the list of methods worked. Shout out to @AloneTogether for the tip to remove batches from the fit function.

```
trainDS = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(trainPaths)
trainDS = (trainDS
    .shuffle(len(trainPaths))
    .map(load_images, num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE)
    .map(augment, num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE)
    .cache('train_cache')
    .batch(batch_size, drop_remainder=True) 
    .prefetch(AUTOTUNE)
    .repeat(2) # <-- put last in the list
)
```

Comment: What's the value of `epochs` ?

Comment: @alionkun epochs are set to 100 but I have a callback for early stopping. 

The model usually stops training after a few learning rate reductions between 15 and 30 epochs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, maybe you should not be explicitly defining the `batch_size` and `steps_per_epoch` in `model.fit(...)`. Regarding the `batch_size` parameter in `model.fit(...)`, the [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model?version=nightly#fit) state:

> [...] Do not specify the batch_size if your data is in the form of datasets,
> generators, or keras.utils.Sequence instances (since they generate
> batches).

This seems to work:

```
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.random.normal((1000, 1))
y = tf.random.normal((1000, 1))

ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x, y)).repeat(2)
ds = ds.shuffle(2000).cache('train_cache').batch(15, drop_remainder=True ).prefetch(tf.data.AUTOTUNE)

val_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((tf.random.normal((300, 1)), tf.random.normal((300, 1))))
val_ds = val_ds.shuffle(300).cache('val_cache').batch(15, drop_remainder=True).prefetch(tf.data.AUTOTUNE)

inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape = (1,))
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='relu')(inputs)
outputs = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)(x)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs, outputs)

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
model.fit(ds, validation_data=val_ds, epochs = 5)
```

```
Epoch 1/5
133/133 [==============================] - 1s 4ms/step - loss: 1.0355 - val_loss: 1.1205
Epoch 2/5
133/133 [==============================] - 0s 3ms/step - loss: 0.9847 - val_loss: 1.1050
Epoch 3/5
133/133 [==============================] - 0s 3ms/step - loss: 0.9810 - val_loss: 1.0982
Epoch 4/5
133/133 [==============================] - 0s 3ms/step - loss: 0.9792 - val_loss: 1.0937
Epoch 5/5
133/133 [==============================] - 0s 3ms/step - loss: 0.9779 - val_loss: 1.0903
<keras.callbacks.History at 0x7f3acb3e5ed0>
```

133 * `batch_size` = 1995 --> remainder was dropped.

Comment: Just saw this and will try in the morning (have to spin up EC2 and do all the ssh stuff and it's late where I am). Thank you for your comment!

Comment: Taking batch_size out of the fit function doesn't seem to help. Using a batch size of 200 for my generator and got 

WARNING:tensorflow:Your input ran out of data; interrupting training. Make sure that your dataset or generator can generate at least `steps_per_epoch * epochs` batches (in this case, 82000 batches). You may need to use the repeat() function when building your dataset.

`hist= model.fit(trainDS, epochs=100, validation_data=valDS)`

Comment: Did you try my example? It’s running perfectly

Comment: I did. I took out batches from the fit function and added repeat to: `from_tensor_slices(trainPaths).repeat(2)` but that raised the same warning. However, when I added it to the list of chained methods it worked. Order mattered a lot more than I realized and having repeat(2) at the very end [see updated question] worked. Still going to accept your answer bc removing batches was a big win.